# can't reach data variable inside function?

Tags: vue.js

I got a computed function that sorts my array, it works good until i wanna be able to sort it after a variable.

Heres how it looks right now:

```js
data: function ()  {
  return {
     closeOnClick: true,
      filterOption: 'title',
  }
```

my actual function here

```js
computed: {

    sortedArray: function() {
      function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.filterOption < b.filterOption)
          return -1;
        if (a.filterOption > b.filterOption)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }

      return this.albums.sort(compare);
    }
  }
```

Whenever i do `console.log(this.filterOption)` it does display the correct value, but for some reason its not filtering after what i want. If i do however type manually in for an example `if (a.title < b.title)` instead of trying to use the variable, the filtering works magic.

**Any ideas why i cant use the variable as im expecting to?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the property specified by `filterOption`, you'll have to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation):

```js
// if (a.filterOption < b.filterOption) ❌ object does not contain property named "filterOption"
if (a[filterOption] < b[filterOption])  ✅ lookup property specified by `filterOption`
```

Also note that [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) mutates the original array, which Vue will warn you about. Use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) beforehand to avoid this mutation:

```js
// return this.albums.sort(compare);       ❌ mutates original array
return this.albums.slice().sort(compare);  ✅ mutates copy
```

The resulting code should look like this:

```js
computed: {
  sortedArray: function() {
    const filterOption = this.filterOption
    function compare(a, b) {
      if (a[filterOption] < b[filterOption])
        return -1;
      if (a[filterOption] > b[filterOption])
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }

    return this.albums.slice().sort(compare);
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-filter-option?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

As `filterOption` is a data object property, You can not directly access this in `computed`. You have to access this with a scope (`this`). Hence, it should be **:**

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a[this.filterOption] < b[this.filterOption])
        return -1;
    if (a[this.filterOption] > b[this.filterOption])
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```